# How to tell if a method in a module is instance method or class method

Tags: ruby, mixins

I understand that `include` creates instance methods and `extend` creates class methods. How do we tell whether a method is instance or class method?

In the following example, it looks like a method is an instance method and a class method. Is there no difference between instance and class methods in some cases?

```
module Test
  def aux
    puts 'aux'
  end
end

class A
  include Test
end

class B
  extend Test
end

a = A.new
a.aux
B.aux
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference between `include` and `extend` is how the *class* that is mixing the module will behave. Both `include` and `extend` will only work on a module's 'instance' methods (that is, methods that don't start with ModuleName or `self`)

Example:

```
module Foo
  def a
    puts "a"
  end

  def Foo.b
    puts "b"
  end

  def self.c
    puts "c"
  end
end
```

a class that *includes* this module will only have access to `a` as an **instance method** while a class that *extends* it while only have access to `a` as a **class method**. Neither will have access to `b` or `c` as those are Foo's class methods and can only be accessed by calling `Foo.b` or `Foo.c`